# “Perfect pitch” equivalent for someone with a good visual sense

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases

If someone with a good sense of tonal hearing can be described as having *perfect pitch*, what is the equivalent phrase or word for someone who has a good visual sense?

Meaning:

> Jane is great at color coordination and color balance. She has good
>   sense of _____.

Or:

> Joe’s ability to detect fine detail in works of art make him a ____.

Comment: Perfect pitch is not just a “good sense of hearing” it is the ability to hear a tone and identify what note it is- which of course means the frequency of the tone.  Therefore the analog in color would be someone who can see a color and identify what? The RGB value? The HSV value? The exact wavelength of light?  I don’t think there is a person alive that can accurately do this and thus there’s no word for it.  A good sense of “color” has more to do with color coordination than exact color identification.

Comment: There really is no equivalent, since *perfect pitch* is not about acuity or even musicality but rather about having reliably internalized the fixed standard whereby concert A is 440 Hz.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A good sense for what colours are attractive in a particular situation is often called an *eye for colour*, *colour sense*, or *sense of colour*.

The ability to resolve fine detail particularly at a distance would often be described as being *eagle eyed* or *hawk eyed*.  More generally a good sense of vision is often described as being *sharp eyed* or having *sharp eyes* or *a sharp eye*.

None of these is equivalent to *perfect pitch* which is much more specific ability to pick out the dominant frequency of a sound as a note and to detect if it's off from the exact frequency it should be for a note.  The equivalent for vision would be being able to pick out the frequency of light we're seeing, but the way our eyes work makes this impossible.  Just having a good sense of hearing would be better described as being *sharp eared* or having *sharp ears*"

Answer (score 8):

There are a few misconceptions. Good hearing doesn't imply perfect pitch. They are separate concepts. Perfect pitch is the ability to discern individual musical notes.

A word for excellent vision is `eagle eyes`. "Joe has eagle eyes. He can see a muskrat from 100 meters."

You can't use `eagle eyed` for Jane. For that sentence you would say "Jane has a good `sense of style`."

Comment: "Perfect pitch is the ability to discern individual musical notes." Discerning between different notes (relative pitch) is very different from "perfect pitch" -- which means identifying the absolute pitch without aid of a reference note.  (most people who can "play a tune by ear" have very good relative pitch abilities, but may or may not have perfect pitch.)

Answer (score 4):

You can say that Jane has a *good sense of colour* and Joe has an *eye for detail*.

Comment: The key is a good colour memory. How I wish I had a good memory for colours!

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest,

***have a discerning/good eye***

> (*idiom*) If a person has a discerning eye, they are particularly good at judging the quality of something. [UsingEnglish](http://www.usingenglish.com/reference/idioms/discerning+eye.html)

***have an eye [for something]***

> To be discriminating or perceptive about something, as in *She has an eye for decorating*. [c. 1700] [AHD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/have+an+eye+for)

Answer (score 1):

I have always called it *perfect plum*.  Tones do not necessarily equate to color.  Visual spacial ability is the core skill.  Just as you can hear the depth of a canyon by the pitch of the echo; so can you see the perpendicularity of a wall or the level of a line.  To discern it to the exact degree; 0-360, without any relative identifying clues; might be equivalent to identifying an exact note.